# Magento 2 : get simple product data using config product id mysql query

Tags: magento2, product, database, magento2.4

I need some help with creating a mysql query
that fetches

a simple product from config product id/sku

a simple product with attributes such as

- id
- name
- sku
- price

Any thoughts how this can be achieved ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?